# How to simplify ruby block with one argument?

Tags: ruby, closures

Somewhere I saw a way to simplify ruby blocks with one argument, it basically omitted vertical bars and argument declaration, because it was somehow inlined.

I cannot find it anymore or remember any names to search for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a simplifications that works in a few situations.

If you have something like:

```
(1..10).collect { |i| i.to_s }
```

You can simplify it to:

```
(1..10).collect(&:to_s)
```

The `&` converts the symbol to a proc by calling [`Symbol#to_proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9/classes/Symbol.html#M000031). It doesn't work with additional arguments, and it only works if you want to invoke a method directly on the block argument. It was [introduced](http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2006/3/7/symbol-to-proc-shorthand) in Rails (ActiveSupport), but made its way into core Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.